# How to hide grid view in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am new to Asp.net. we created a grid view to display data in the webpage. initially the grid view data need to be hide. after clicking the search button it should get display according to the search criteria.

Comment: `grdView.Visible=false;`

Comment: Don't bind your gridview on `Page_Load`, bind when you click on search. This way nothing will be shown on your page until you press search button. One more thing As mentioned in your post you are new to asp.net then please visit [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w3ex9c2.aspx) and start from basics.

Comment: Sure will visit that site.. also please suggest some sites, about ASP.Net tutorials videos, Material with examples, and books

Answer (score 0):

on Page_Load have

```
yourGridView.Visible = False;
```

Then on your button Click event have:

```
if(it_should_show) //depending on your search criteria
{
    yourGridView.Visible = True;
}
```